# I am having trouble getting multithreading working in my Python project

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I am having trouble getting the threading to work in my code. If I take the threading out the for loop appends the menu.txt to  menu = []. For my homework I need to change this so that it is working with a thread. This is what I have so far but I keep coming up with an exception 'module' object is not callable. I feel like I am close but I am missing something.

This is itemClass.py -

```
class item(Thread): #class for the menu items
    def __init__(self, name, wholeSale, retail, orderCount):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.wholeSale = wholeSale
        self.retail = retail
        self.orderCount = orderCount
```

This is guiMain.py -

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import manager
import restaurant
import itemClass
import threading
from threading import *

if __name__ == "__main__":

    menu = []

    t1 = itemClass.item()
    t1.start()

    with open("menu.txt") as f: #reads menu.txt to store in menu variable
        for line in f.readlines():
            arr = line.split(",")
            menu.append(t1(arr[0],float(arr[1]),float(arr[2]),int(arr[3])))
```

mainGUI(menu)

This is menu.txt -

```
Chicken Sandwich,3.5,4.99,16
Spicy Chicken Sandwich,3.75,5.49,21
Chicken Tender Box,4.17,5.99,22
Spicy Tender Box,4.38,6.49,10
Fries,1.15,2.99,22
```

The Exception Being Thrown -

```
Message=item.__init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'name', 
'wholeSale', 'retail', and 'orderCount'
```

Source=C:\Users\neodr\Desktop\PythonClass\Lesson10_2051495\Lesson10Project2_2051495\guiMain.py
StackTrace:
File
"C:\Users\neodr\Desktop\PythonClass\Lesson10_2051495\Lesson10Project2_2051495\guiMain.py", line 46, in  (Current frame)
t1 = itemClass.item()

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Is there a newline at the end of your file?

Comment: At the end of menu.txt there is a blank line

Comment: Wait a minute.  You have a class called `item`, but you are creating `t1 = itemClass()`.  Where is `itemClass`?  And your thread doesn't do anything -- you don't have a `start` or `run` function.  It looks like a storage container.  What actions are you supposed to be taking that would take advantage of threading?

Comment: I edited it. It was originally itemClass.item() but I forgot to switch it back when I was playing with things. This is just a small part of a large project where I have to introduce threading through out. I was just trying to get it to work on the first part so I can understand how to change the rest of the project. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK, now I see.  You did `import itemClass`, and then `itemClass.item` is that class from above.  Still, the problem stands that your thread doesn't do anything.  You'll need to tell us more about what the threading is supposed to do.

Comment: Here is the description from the homework assignment - Add an application of threads to your restaurant project. Include a class that inherits threading and then allows the program to move on to other operations.  Create threads for a log file. For example, when an object is created log it out with threads. Also add a log thread that is started each time an order object is added to the totals object. Don't let the program complete before all the logs are closed.

Comment: It is possible I am just going about this completely wrong. This is my first time ever dealing with threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you describe is a basic one, and doesn't actually have anything to do with threading per se. The `itemClass.item` class you've defined expects to be given four arguments. You're not doing that when you try to create an instance of the class in your GUI code. When you do `t1 = itemClass.item()`, you're not passing any arguments. Later in your code you try to call `t1` with arguments, but that's not supported either (an instance of your class is not callable).

None of this makes much sense. I suspect the underlying problem is that you're trying to insert threading into a place it doesn't make any sense. You should want a thread to be running where you have ongoing stuff happening and you want it to continue to happen while you're doing something else in the main thread. The part of your code that you've shown doesn't seem like it matches up with that. You're just defining menu items here. There's nothing ongoing that needs a thread.

It is likely that you need to rethink the structure of this code and put the threading somewhere else. For instance, it might make sense for a menu item, once selected, to start up a thread that keeps running in the background. But the thread creation would then be triggered by GUI stuff (selecting from the menu), not created and started up front when the menu items are being defined.

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake in my original post. I fixed that but it is still not working.

Comment: Can you edit your question to also show the exception you're getting? Give the full traceback! The `module object not callable` message made sense for the original version of the code, but doesn't any more (you should get `item object not callable` now). Also, you should show your imports, because running the `guiMain` code you show if run verbatim would give an error that `itemClass` is undefined.

Comment: I think I have everything you asked for.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your error is still a basic one, before any real threading issues come up. But there likely *are* major threading issues with your design, so I comment on them too. Basically: there's no need for a thread in the code you've shown, it probably belongs elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. I am pretty new at Python and threading. I had a feeling maybe my threading just didn't belong here. I will take a look at my code and see if I can come up with different solution based off of you suggestions for adding threading to my project. I get what threading is supposed to do but I am not sure I am understanding how it is supposed to be implemented properly.

Comment: Based on the assignment text you gave in another comment, you may want an application thread that does whatever your program is mostly about, a GUI thread (possibly the main thread) to do GUI stuff, and a logging thread to keep the logs updated (or possibly one thread per log file).

Answer (score 0):

1.you havent defined itemClass anywhere so i assume you ment item so try:
from itemClass import item

```
 t1 = item()
```

2.you havent passed any arguments to init method of item class

3.it is not clear what are you trying to achive with the thread